# A region is simply connected if $\theta < 2\pi$, and not simply connected if $\theta \ge 2\pi$

Tags: calculus, connectedness

The question is:
Which of the following regions are simply-connected? (...)

e) in polar coordinates, the region where $r>0,0<\theta<\theta_0$.

The solution says:

[simply connected] if $\theta_0<2\pi$, no if $\theta_0\ge2\pi$, since then R is the plane with $(0,0)$ removed.

What is the logic behind the answer? How come that $(0,0)$ sort of removes itself when $\theta_0\ge2\pi$?

I've checked answers like [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1798923/why-is-a-circle-not-simply-connected) and [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1480101/a-line-is-simply-connected-but-a-circle-is-not-does-this-mean-that-the-one-poin?rq=1), but (although the first adds intuition) they delve into topology, which is too much for me at this point.

This question comes from Multivariable Calculus course (for reference, [exercise 4G-5](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-02sc-multivariable-calculus-fall-2010/3.-double-integrals-and-line-integrals-in-the-plane/part-b-vector-fields-and-line-integrals/problem-set-8/MIT18_02SC_SupProb4.pdf)), not from Topology course, so please don't use into (too much) topology.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$(0,0)$ is excluded by the requirement $r>0$. Though technically since you said $0<\theta<\theta_0$ (both bounds strict) the case $\theta_0=2\pi$ is still simply connected, because $\{ (r,\theta) : r>0,0<\theta<2\pi \}$ corresponds to the plane minus the nonnegative $x$ axis.

The intuitive reason why the plane with a hole in the origin isn't simply connected is because you can draw a circle containing the origin and then you can't continuously contract it to a point; no matter what you do, either at some point you will cross the origin or else the origin will be inside the loop throughout the process.

The intuitive reason why a wedge with the origin cut out of it is simply connected is that you can't draw a loop that encloses the origin at all, so any loop can be contracted to a point other than the origin.

Answer (score 1):

The point $(0,0)$ belongs to none of those regions (and therefore $(0,0)$ doesn't get suddenly removed). However, if $\theta_0\geqslant2\pi$, the region is $\Bbb R^2\setminus\bigl\{(0,0)\bigr\}$, which is not simply connected.

On the other hand, if $\theta_0<2\pi$, then, given any point $p$ of the regien, the line segment that goes from $p$ to $\left(\cos\left(\frac{\theta_0}2\right),\sin\left(\frac{\theta_0}2\right)\right)$ is contained in the region. [Therefore](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1748528/every-star-shaped-set-is-simply-connected), the region is simply connected.