# A simply/path-connected set that is not star-shaped

Tags: integration, general-topology, complex-analysis, path-connected

I come across this definition while studying complex analysis:

> An (open) set $U \subset \mathbb C$ is **star-shaped**  there exists a point $a_0$ such that for all $w\in U$ the line segment connecting $w$ and $a_0$ lies completely inside $U$.

With this definition, we proceed to prove the Cauchy-Goursat Theorem of Integrals for Star Domains:

> If in a star-shaped domain $U$, we have a holomorphic function $f$ and a piecewise smooth closed curve $\gamma$, then $\int_\gamma f(z) dz = 0$.

And when I continue my studying, most of the application (such as solving integrals) relies on the fact that $U$ is a [simply connected](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simply_connected_space) set. By reading [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1748528/every-star-shaped-set-is-simply-connected), I also found that $U$ is star-shaped $\Rightarrow$ $U$ is simply connected $\Rightarrow$ $U$ is [path-connected](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_space#Path_connectedness).

I also heard from others that the Cauchy-Goursat Theorem of Integrals for Star Domains is a theorem stronger than required. So does there exists a set such that

- $U$ is simply connected but not star-shaped?
- $U$ is path-connected but not star-shaped?

Thank you!

Comment: I do not understand the question. You already found that a star-shaped domain is simply connected.

Comment: With other words, since $A\Rightarrow B$ is logically equivalent to $\neg B\Rightarrow\neg A$, such a star-shaped set can not exist. Also it might be worth to mention that open balls are star-shaped, so it is quite common.

Comment: Note that to be path connected, you need to be able to connect every point to every other with a path.  To be star shaped,  you need a single point that has a straight line path to every other point.  So if you are star shaped, you can always create a path between any 2 points by just travelling from one point to the star point to the other point

Comment: My bad, I should ask the question in its converse form as edited. Thank you all for pointing it out.

Comment: The definition of star-shaped can't be right. It must be "there exists $a_0$ such that for every $w$," not the other way around.

Comment: Thank you Gerry. I originally thought that they are no difference but I am just too careless. The definition is edited. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Half of an annulus will do the job. In terms of an equation,
$$\{(x, y) \in \Bbb R^2 : 1 \leqslant x^2 + y^2 \leqslant 2, \ x \geqslant 0\}.$$
Do you see why this satisfies both your conditions?